# ng-change works incorrect?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I have one code:

```
<select ng-options="i.id as i.os_version for i in devices"
        ng-model="selected_version_os_to" 
        ng-change="selectVersion(i.id)">
    <option value=''> Select version</option>
</select>
```

Why I get `undefined` in console when try to display value in:

`ng-change="selectVersion(i.id)"`?

Inside `selectVersionfunction`: I get `i.id` as undefined:

```
$scope.selectVersion = function(item) { 
    console.log(item); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to pass anything in `selectVersion` method, as `ng-model` already binding selected value for you.

Your code should be like:

```
<select ng-options="i.id as i.os_version for i in devices"
        ng-model="selected_version_os_to" 
        ng-change="selectVersion()">
    <option value=''> Select version</option>
</select>


// controller code
$scope.selectVersion = function() { 
    console.log($scope.selected_version_os_to); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to display the wrong variable.
As your `ng-model` is `ng-model="selected_version_os_to"`, you should change your `ng-change` to:

```
ng-change="selectVersion(selected_version_os_to)"
```